# what fires the onerror event handler for object tags in ie?

Tags: javascript, flash, internet-explorer, object, onerror

we have been doing some testing on some embeded flash widgets.

while i know the **onerror event**, when attached to a **object tag** is not very cross browser friendly, we are getting this handler called quite a bit for internet explorer users.

while i am quite sure this handler will be called when the swf cannot be loaded (as in, 404, 410, network error, etc), is it called in any other circumstances?

as these widgets are not our own, is it possible to 'throw' an onerror event from within the embeded flash file? if so, this could be why we are seeing this.

i guess i should throw this in as well, is it possible to get any additional information as to what caused the onerror event to be called when it is called?

to summarize, what we are looking for is to know weather it is safe to assume that IF an onerror event is fired from an object tag, that it was fired because the swf did not load successfully, and thus we can attempt to load it from another url. yea, we just don't want to try reloading the swf if onerror was fired for some OTHER reason then the swf failing to load.

some additional information:

we are using the flash satay method of embeding flash. and simply adding the onerror to the object tag, as follows:

```
<object .... onerror="ourAjaxLogFunction()">
```

as always, thank you kindly.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197053.aspx) for `onerror` says (emphasis mine):

> To invoke, cause one of the following errors to occur:
>
> - Run-time script error, such as an invalid object reference **or
>     security violation**.
> - Error while downloading an object, such as an image.
> - New for Internet Explorer 9. An error occurs
>     while fetching media data.

Maybe your Flash content is trying to cross a security boundary of some kind. If that's the case, trying to reload it from another source won't help things. I'd suggest you perform further investigations on the error messages passed to your handler.

Comment: may i ask how do we access the 'error message'? my only past experience is on window.onerror for logging js errors. currently we are attaching it as mentioned, object .... onerror="logFunction()"

Comment: @anonymous, three arguments are passed to your `onerror` handler: the error message, the source URL, and the line number. `function ourAjaxLogFunction(message, source, line) {    /* ... */ }`